# 'Dir' where path contains spaces under windows doesn't work? (ruby)

Tags: ruby

not sure if it matters that I run the code from haml

this line works nicely

```
- files = Dir['*']
```

but here I suspect the spaces in the path....

```
- files = Dir["C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework410\Output Files\builds\*.xml"]
```

Comment: it depends what I want to do. Compare the answer with this one: `directorylist = %x[cd C:\\Program Files\\TestPro\\TestPro Automation Framework410 && dir]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most unicode style strings use escape character `\` but windows allows both `\` and `/` for path declarations.

```
- files = Dir["C:/Program Files/TestPro/TestPro Automation Framework410/Output Files/builds/*.xml"]
```

Comment: `- files = Dir["C:/Program Files/TestPro/TestPro Automation Framework410/Output Files/builds/*.xml"]` is the answer